# Go back previous ViewController from NavigationController in TabViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I got the problem is I cannot make go back previous ViewController of different storyboard from NavigationController in TabViewController.

I've already tried with

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

unfortunately, it does not work. And I know that it can be going back with `segue` but it's not good practice. Please let me know how to do it. Thanks. Following is my hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate more? - you are going from which controller to which controller? how many controllers are there in your navigation controller array?

Comment: to Controller of another storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  In this case I am on a different Storyboard and want to return to the Main Storyboard and present the first view controller.  Since this controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller that is embedded in a Tab Bar controller, you must instantiate the Tab Bar Controller. Be sure to set the indentifier on the Tab Bar Controller as "TabBarController"... or whatever you like.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: that one is same as what I said `segue`

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't understand.

Comment: what wrote is same as `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeSegue", sender: nil)`  that's what I said in my question.

Comment: That is not what you asked in your question.  Furthermore, you are not referencing the Tab Bar Controller anywhere.